# The type or namespace name 'GridViewDataColumn' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress

I want to loop through Gridview(Devexpress Control).

Getting this weird error while compiling the project.

> The type or namespace name 'GridViewDataColumn' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thought it was related to target framework cause I have 2 projects in same solution and both were pointing to different target framework. Changed from Target framework 3.5 to 4.0 for both projects but no luck

Am i missing any DLL file. I am using Devexpress 14.1 controls.

this is my code behind :

```
foreach (GridViewDataColumn Column in dx_Approval.Columns)
{
    Column.SettingsHeaderFilter.Mode = headerFilterMode;
}
```

Where dx_Approval is my Gridview(Devexpress Control)

Comment: Did you add using DevExpress.Web; on the top of your file and did you add the reference to DevExpress.Web.v15.2.dll library?

Comment: I have added Devexpress.Web.v14.1 as i am using 14.1 controls. still getting the same error.

Comment: Try to change your foreach to next code: `foreach (DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataColumn Column in dx_Approval.Columns)` or `foreach (var Column in dx_Approval.Columns)` I think that var will helps you.

Comment: I tried both ways. in var foreach I am getting error at SettingHeaderFilter as "Object does not contain a definition for" error.

Comment: Sorry can't solve your problem. The last error means that you should enumerate only GridViewDataColumn  columns for example `foreach (var Column in dx_Approval.Columns.Where(x => x as DevExpress.Web.GridViewDataColumn)` but you have another error.